# Error when importing jar file in Eclipse (even after adding it to the build path)

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

In the 'lib' directory of my Eclipse project, I have a jar file, 'foo.jar' which contains a class file 'Foo.class' **in the (default package) of 'foo.jar'**, which I have added to my build path in Eclipse (using Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries->Add JARs...). Now, 'foo.jar' appears under the 'Referenced Libraries' section in Eclipse's Package Explorer.

In the 'src' directory of my project I've got a file 'bar.java' whose first line is:

```
import foo.Foo;
```

In the body of 'bar.java', the code can use the contents of 'Foo.class' and all appears well, except I get exactly one error, on the import statement: "The import foo cannot be resolved", so the program won't run; it's the only error in 'bar.java'.

What's the proper way to take care of this?

(I have cleaned the project and refreshed it.)

Comment: `import xxx.Foo;`  where xxx is the package name, not the name of the jar

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks. However I'm not sure how to do that, since 'Foo.class' is in the (default package) of 'foo.jar', and changing the import to `import Foo;` doesn't work (it has the same error).

Comment: Perhaps you don't need to import it, then?  Just try using `Foo`?

Comment: Indeed! That fixed it. What a simple solution. Do you mind submitting that as an answer so I can mark this as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import xxx.Foo; where xxx is the package name, not the name of the jar

If it's the default package, just try using Foo?  You won't need the import in that case.

Thanks m8 ;)